# SwiftUI - creating a class error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to Swift and am trying to create a simple class 'Cat.swift' and then to pass the class to my SceneDelegate file which then passes it to my ContentView file.

however, I keep getting the 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments' error and the build keeps failing.

Cat.swift code

```
class Cat {
    var breed: String = ""
    var personality: String = ""
    var colour: String = ""
    var characterisitics: String = ""

    init(bre: String, pers: String, col: String, chars: String) {
        breed = bre
        personality = pers
        colour = col
        characterisitics = chars
    }
}
```

SceneDelegate.swift code

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    let cat = Cat(bre: "ooo", pers: "ppp", col: "ppp", chars: "ppp")

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let contentView = ContentView(cat: cat)
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

ContentView.swift file

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("bugggggy\(cat.bre)")
        }
    }


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(cat: Cat(bre: "p", pers: "p", col: "p", chars: "p"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your ContentView and its constructor?

Comment: There’s no point in using `self.`if you turn all the argument labels into gibberish!

Comment: @Jessy 
Yeah, you're totally right. Thanks for the tip! 
I'll do better next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there is not constructor with argument cat of ContentView
so Xcode reminds you of that.

the code below can solve your problem but not sure it's what you expected.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    private var cat: Cat

    init(cat: Cat) {
        self.cat = cat
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I realize now how silly my error was!
I must have just needed to step away from it and come back. 
Sorry if I wasted your time. :)